# How to add a break between two Code Blocks?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

Having just read the formatting help provided within the post editor and also the advanced formatting help for *Code & Preformatted Text*, I can't seem to find a way to add a break between two or more code blocks, without including some irrelevant text in between.

**For example:**

```
SELECT 
    e.firstname, e.surname, w.salary
FROM
    Employees e LEFT JOIN Wages w ON e.ID = w.employee
ORDER BY
    w.salary DESC
```

*(Some irrelevant text to separate the code blocks)*

```
(defun factorial ( n )
    (if (< 1 n)
        (* n (factorial (1- n)))
        1
    )
)
```

**Without such text, the code blocks are always merged:**

```
SELECT 
    e.firstname, e.surname, w.salary
FROM
    Employees e LEFT JOIN Wages w ON e.ID = w.employee
ORDER BY
    w.salary DESC


(defun factorial ( n )
    (if (< 1 n)
        (* n (factorial (1- n)))
        1
    )
)
```

Is there some markup that I'm overlooking to achieve this?

Comment: I use a `<!— ... —>` html comment. Use it as an opportunity to add a correct language highlighter tag.  Or more commonly, actual text to explain what the next codeblock is about.

Answer (score 6):

I found it easiest in such case to use a horizontal line like so:

```
code
```

---

```
more code
```

Markup looks like

```
    code

---

    more code
```

---

Another way is to put an invisible HTML tag between the blocks (as pointed out in [@Mat's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376196/how-to-add-a-break-between-two-code-blocks#comment643656_376197)):

```
code
```

```
more code
```

Markup:

```
    code
<!-- -->

    more code
```

---

> *Some irrelevant text to separate the code blocks*

Well, alternatively make that text ***relevant*** to explain why you are separating those code blocks.

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with this, what the asker is apparenty asking is for a way to separate code-blocks without inserting any other character between them. Presumably what they want is for a way to insert a blank linke between blanks. Resorting to an horizontal line is conceptually the same as typing any other character, it simple adds content between the blocks. This is yet another thing that would be better if SE adopted the use of fenced code-blocks.

Comment: @yivi Both of us well know, that there's no way to add _blank_ lines between code blocks in markup (or do you know a trick to do so?).

Comment: @Mat I'd prefer the explanation variant though.

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes you just want two snippets.

Comment: @Mat I've added that option you proposed.